# Manipular objecto json

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte `json`:

```
{
   "home":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "menu":"1",
         "title":"Titulo 1",
         "image":"image01.jpg",
         "url":"http:\/\/www.exemplo.pt\/images\/image01.jpg"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "menu":"3",
         "title":"Titulo 2",
         "image":"image02.jpg",
         "url":"http:\/\/www.exemplo.pt\/images\/image02.jpg"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "menu":"4",
         "title":"Titulo 3",
         "image":"image03.jpg",
         "url":"http:\/\/www.exemplo.pt\/images\/image03.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Já experimentei os seguintes métodos mas ambos acabam por dar erro:
**`JSONArray`**

```
try {
    JSONArray JOBJECT = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    JSONArray home = JOBJECT.getJSONArray(0);
    JSONArray home_idx_1 = home.getJSONArray(0);
    String image = home_idx_1.getString(0);

    Log.v("view content", image);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**`JSONObject`**

```
try {
    JSONObject JOBJECT = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject home = JOBJECT.getJSONObject("home");
    JSONArray home_idx_1 = home.getJSONArray("0");
    String image = home_idx_1.getString("image");

    Log.v("view content", image);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Como posso fazer para armazenar o valor de `image` do índice `2` do array `home` na variável `image`?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a biblioteca `Gson` do Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que o seu **home** é um *array* de objetos, então experimente assim:

```
try {
    JSONObject JOBJECT = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray array = JOBJECT.getJSONArray("home");
    JSONObject home_idx_1 = array.getJSONObject(0);
    String image = home_idx_1.getString("image");

    Log.v("view content", image);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Isso para que o seu código funcione. Agora, para obter o índice 2 como você perguntou, acredito que vai ser preciso iteragir sobre o `array` até chegar no índice desejado.